# Adding a column to one table for every row in another in SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm pretty much brand new to SQL so I apologize if this is a silly question.

I'm trying to build a very basic LMS in Wordpress and am getting a little tripped up on my SQL logic.

Right now I have a users table (contains each users data) and a quizzes table (contains the content for each quiz), each time I add a new quiz to the quizzes table I want to add a column to my user table that will contain a boolean field to track whether or not the user has completed the new quiz.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, or if I should use a join table to combine them somehow? Any advice on the direction I should be going here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: First, do NOT do it that way, it will create a nightmare for maintenance.  Create another table that combines both.  It would be a simple relatinoship table, call it something like UsersCompletedQuizes (or something) and it would have UserID, QuizeID  (so you only insert a record once they complete the quiz, you do not insert a record for the quizid unless they complete it.  Then if you need to find if they have quizzes to complete you would just query this table and the quiz table, and any quizzes not found in UserQuiz table, are ones they need to take

Comment: This seems like it would end up with a lot of duplicate information, for instance if user a completes quiz 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 I would end up with 5 separate records for that individual user in the UsersCompletedQuizes table. I understand your logic doing it this way, but it seems like it would result in much larger data sets than would really be necessary? It might just be the way SQL is set up but I would hope there would be a more elegant solution than this.

Comment: Foreign key is the way to go if you wanted to track per-student achievements. Don't add new column for each row, it's nightmare as explained by @Brad. There are already answers to this thread and I like Edward's answer. There are clearly inches to be gained but it can do the job.

Comment: Thanks guys, the help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the correct way to implement `SQL` functionality.

Instead you will want to create a third table that establishes a relationship between users  and their completed quizzes. It will look something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE users_completed_quizzes ( 
-- completion_id INT IDENTITY 
, user_id  INT 
, quiz_id  INT
, score    FLOAT
, notes    NVARCHAR(255)
-- , PRIMARY KEY (user_id , quiz_id) -- PK One
-- , PRIMARY KEY (relationship_id) -- PK Two 
, FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES Quizzes(id)
, FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(id) 
)
```

For each quiz a user completes, you `insert` a record into this table that contains the user's `user_id` and the quiz's `quiz_id`. I've added some other fields as well so that you can keep track of additional data like their score or any relevant notes on how that quiz went.

You will see some lines are greyed out. These relate to the primary key of your table. This is the `field` that will uniquely identify the records on the table.

**Determine which primary key you would like to use.**

The first one is a composite of the Foreign Keys. This is fairly standard and is easy to think through, but can be harder to use. It will also be more difficult to implement the same users taking the same quiz multiple times with this method.

The second one is a unique identity column. This is an autoincrement number that will track each insertion of a new record. It is easier to use, but may be harder to follow logically for new users. It is easier to implement quiz history with this method.

If you choose to use the second primary key, the you must un-comment the top line to add that field to the table.

If you choose to use the first primary key, then you will need to remove the comma before `user_id` in order to keep proper syntax.

Do not use both Primary Keys (PKs). SQL will get mad at you if you attempt to do so.

Comments are signified by `--`.

---

Some examples on what queries would look like for the Primary Key One.

```
-- returns all the quizzes a single user has completed. 
SELECT quiz_id FROM users_completed_quizzes WHERE user_id = '1'

-- returns all quizzes that have not been completed by a any user. 
SELECT id FROM Quizzes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users_completed_quizzes 
ON Quizzes.id = users_completed_quizzes.quiz_id 
WHERE quiz_id = NULL;

-- returns all quizzes that have been completed by at least one user. 
SELECT id FROM Quizzes 
WHERE id EXISTS (SELECT quiz_id FROM users_completed_quizzes)

-- returns user and quiz info using the association table. 
SELECT quiz_id, user_id , Users.region , Quizzes.category
FROM users_completed_quizzes
INNER JOIN Users ON 
 Users.id = users_completed_quizzes.user_id
INNER JOIN Quizzes ON 
 Quizzes.id = users_completed_quizzes.quiz_id
```

---

Once a user has completed a quiz, you will need a `sql` statement to be executed that looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO users_completed_quizzes (user_id , quiz_id) -- you can add more fields here if you wish. 
VALUES ( {User's Id from Users.id} , {Quiz's Id from Quizzes.id} )
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation and the working code, It is very much appreciated! It was very hard for me to first conceptualize this because I'm more used to working with OOP but SQL is another beast indeed!

The LMS will be very simple so all I will use this table to track is whether or not a quiz has been completed. In which case it makes more sense to use the first PK? Then I can just query this table to see it the user_id & quiz_id exists in the same record?

Comment: Yes. I will add some examples of what the query would look like using the first PK.

Comment: Take care with what happens when a user attempts to re-take the same quiz when using the Primary Key One method. You will get an error when the `insert` statement I provided is run when a `user` and `quiz` are already associated on the `users_completed_quizzes` table. This is because `SQL` will see this as a `duplicate key`. This may actually be a good thing if you want to totally prevent retakes. Of course it is still possible to change the data model to allow for quiz re-takes in the future if you find it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, the quizzes will only be able to be take once and I will be using the query to disable access to quizzes once they are complete so this shouldn't be an issue.